# WPF DataGrid User Control - adding a new column in a view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a user control that has a Datagrid that has 3 columns. I want to use this user control in a view but I need to add one more column to the Datagrid but **only** in this view.

Is this possible?

Code on the view

```
// Initialising the Usercontrol on the new view
xmlns:myuct="clr-namespace:Customer.UserControls">
<Grid>
    <myuct:CustomerSearch x:Name="CS"/>
</Grid>
```

This shows the Datagrid and other items of the user control in the view correctly.

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest that you make your usercontrol accept a flag or switch that can show and hide the additional column. Use DependencyProperties so that you can set the flag/switch in XAML.

```
// Initialising the Usercontrol on the new view
xmlns:myuct="clr-namespace:Customer.UserControls">
<Grid>
    <myuct:CustomerSearch x:Name="CS" ShowAddOnColumn="true"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I like this method, so basically so I understand, use a DependencyProperty in the UserControl View called "ShowAddOnColumn" that will hide/show the DataGrid column, so for clarify sake, I am guessing the DataGrid library has a property to allow to hide/show columns?

Comment: Yes there is a Visibility property for DataGrid column. You can show and hide a column using this property. However, when I propose this, I was thinking about adding the additional column programatically in the usercontrol code, that way you are not holding up some memory in the background, which is not useful in views that does not need to show the column. Either way will work, depends on which fits your usage the best.

Answer (score 0):

To programatically add a column:

```
DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn(); 
textColumn.Header = "First Name"; 
textColumn.Binding = new Binding("FirstName"); 
dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn);
```